# How to get the script from a Locale object on Android?

Tags: java, android, localization, locale, chinese-locale

From what I see the [Android Locale class](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html) doesn't mention anything about the script, only the language, country and variant.

Whereas the [Java SE Locale class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) mentions language, country, **script**, variant and extensions, and of course has a method [getScript()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#getScript%28%29) to get the script.

So, my question is: **How to get the script from a Locale object on Android?**

or is there another way to get the script?

I need this to be able to differentiate between Chinese Traditional (zho-Hant) and Chinese Simplified (zho-Hans), for that I need to be able to get the script from the Locale, e.g. Hant or Hans for the language zho

script =

> ISO 15924 alpha-4 script code. You can find a full list of valid
>   script codes in the IANA Language Subtag Registry (search for "Type:
>   script"). The script field is case insensitive, but Locale always
>   canonicalizes to title case (the first letter is upper case and the
>   rest of the letters are lower case).
>       Well-formed script values have the form [a-zA-Z]{4}
>       Example: "Latn" (Latin), "Cyrl" (Cyrillic)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16447807/get-an-iso-15924-script-code-for-a-given-ietf-language-tag-or-iso-639-iso-3166 Still would like a better answer though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This feature is not built into the *Android SDK*. Instead, I wrote a version you can use, available [here](https://gist.github.com/phil-brown/8056700). Basically, it takes the table in the above answer and ports it to a `Map<String, Map<String, String>>` containing the useful information, then a simple lookup method is used. To use this class in your project, just call:

```
String script = LocaleUtilities.getScript(Locale.getDefault());
```

to get the script for the default locale.