# getScript alternative for Android API 19

Tags: java, android, android-compatibility, android-api-levels

I have an application in Android API level 21 and it's currently using the getScript method which was added in the same api level in class Locale.

The application must have backwards compatibility with Android API level 19 and I need another equivalent way to implement this method.

[**This is the link to the Class with the getScript method**](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html#getScript%28%29)

Here is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19153384/how-to-get-the-script-from-a-locale-object-on-android) I have found already on stackoverflow. Since it has been a long time, is there any better or more efficient way to do this ?