# How to get the full language code for default locale (e.g. zh-hans)

Tags: android, locale

It seems that `Locale.getDefault().getLanguage()` only returns the language code (e.g. `en` or `zh`). Is there a way to get the full language code and script (e.g. `zh-hans` and `en-us`)? `Locale.getDefault().getScript()` is API 21+, and it seems to return the empty string even on applicable OSes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use simply `toString`

```
Locale.getDefault().toString()
```

Or if you need a script separately, take a look at
[How to get the script from a Locale object on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19153384/how-to-get-the-script-from-a-locale-object-on-android)